# Partial derivative or something else?

Tags: vector-spaces, partial-derivative

In the formula for the Reimann tensor[image]

Wikipedia says that $$∂_μ=\frac{∂}{∂x^μ}$$ and that they are coordianates of a vector field. But does it just mean the partial derivative of what comes after is with respect to $x^μ$ or something different, if so what? Thanks.

Comment: $\partial_{\mu}$ is a 4-vector gradient and some explanation can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-gradient

Comment: @Leucippus has a good point, in Einstein notation using $i=1,2,3$ whereas $\mu = 0, 1, 2, 3$ with metric $\eta = \text{diag}(-1,1,1,1)$ we have $3$-D Laplacian $\triangle^2 = \partial_i\partial^i$ or the D'Alembertian $\Box^2=\partial^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}$ which, in a sense, is the $4$-D Laplacian for special relativity. I joke that $\circ^2$ should be the Laplacian for an infinite dimensional space. I have seen a pentagon used for $5$-dimensions in a talk by  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_van_Nieuwenhuizen . Also, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert_operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $V$ is a vector field on a manifold then $V$ is a derivation on smooth functions of the manifold. It turns out that locally this means $V$ is expressed as a sum of partial derivatives with respect to manifold coordinates. In particular,
$$ V  = \sum_{i=1}^n V(x^i) \partial_i $$
The coordinate partial derivatives provide a convenient basis to express vector fields. The Riemann tensor you mention in your question is actually just the component of the Riemann tensor. In particular, 
$$ R = \sum_{\rho, \alpha, \beta, \gamma} R^{\rho}_{ \ \alpha \beta \gamma} \partial_{\rho} \otimes dx^{\alpha} \otimes dx^{\beta}\otimes dx^{\gamma} $$
Then,
$$  R(dx^{\rho}, \partial_{\alpha},  \partial_{\beta}, \partial_{\gamma}) = R^{\rho}_{ \ \alpha \beta \gamma} $$.
In short, $\partial_1$ plays the same role as $\hat{i}$ in multivariable calculus.